# App closes on startup on Flutter (iOS) with Firebase with out giving any error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

The application is working fine on android, however, when I am opening the application on iOS, it crashes instantly without giving any error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem just by moving below line at the top of the function.

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Put the above line as the first instruction in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. Like below.

```
override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
```